# what should be the Salesforce batch job Submitted time if the batch job is QUEUED?

Tags: batch

If a Salesforce batch job kicked at 3:00 pm and due to Queue creation at salesforce(if more than required batch are running simultaneously), than what should be the Apex job time stamp for submitted Date time?

it should be Submitted time=3:00pm or the actual time when the Batch did started executing.

what should be the Salesforce batch job Submitted time if the batch job is QUEUED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this was causing some erroneous results in production due t large No of batches running.

I have Figured it out by re-creating such scenario over the DEV.

The Submitted time is the very first time when the batch has been triggered. either in a queue or under execution.